# How to split a comma separated string into groups of 2 each and then convert all these groups to an array

Tags: php

I have a string which is like `1,2,2,3,3,4` etc. First of all, I want to make them into groups of strings like `(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)`. Then how I can make this string to array like`{(1,2) (2,3) (3,4)}`. Why I want this is because I have a array full of these 1,2 etc values and I've put those values in a `$_SERVER['query_string']="&exp=".$exp`. So Please give me any idea to overcome this issue or solve.Currently this is to create a group of strings but again how to make this array.

```
function x($value)
{
    $buffer = explode(',', $value);
    $result = array();

    while(count($buffer))
    {
        $result[] = sprintf('%d,%d', array_shift($buffer), array_shift($buffer));
    }

    return implode(',', $result);
}

$result = x($expr);
```

but its not working towards my expectations

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand. You can create pairs of numbers like:

```
$string = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
$arr = array_chunk(explode(',', $string), 2);
```

This will give you something like:

```
array(
    array(1, 2),
    array(3, 4),
    array(5, 6)
)
```

If you wanted to turn them into a query string, you'd use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/http_build_query) with some data massaging.

Edit: You can build the query like this (100% UNtested):

```
$numbers = array_map(function($pair) {
    return array($pair[0] => $pair[1]);
}, $arr);

$query_string = '?' . http_build_query($numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
echo '<pre>';

$str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8';
preg_match_all('/(\d+,\d+)(?=,*)/', $str, $matches);

$pairs = $matches[0];

print_r($pairs);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,2
    [1] => 3,4
    [2] => 5,6
    [3] => 7,8
)
```

Comment: the variable $matches, what value does it have

Comment: `$matches` is an array of arrays, in this example it contains the overall matches at `[0]`  and the group matches at `[1]`.  If the `(?:)` group was used only `[0]` would be present.  That would be `/(?:\d+,\d+)(?=,*)/`